# Editing the treeview of an XML and then overwrite the XML file with the new data

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, treeview

I have created a WinForm which loads an XML file and populate it into a treeview. After editing some of the nodes in the treeview, I want to update the same into the existing XML file. I am able to edit the data in the treeview as of now but I am unable to save the same back to the XML file. Please help me know how to save the data back to the XML file.

Comment: See posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578417/save-to-xml-from-treeview

Comment: Thanks jdweng, I got the solution for this question! :)